# How to make a GET request with cljs-ajax to a source outside my server

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript, cljs-ajax

I'm trying to make a simple GET request with clojurescript using cljs-ajax to a resource outside my server. My code core.cljs looks like this:

```
(ns btc-data-miner.core
    (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]
              [ajax.core :refer [GET POST]]))

(defn handler [response]
    (.log js/console (str response)))

(defn error-handler [{:keys [status status-text]}]
    (.log js/console (str "something bad happened: " status " " status-text)))

(GET "www.okcoin.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=btc_usd" {:handler handler
                                                           :error-handler error-handler})
```

But it always searches for files inside my website, as if a was passing /resource instead of the full path. How can I make the request to outside sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www.okcoin.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=btc_usd` is a relative URL.  So it will be resolved relative the current page (which, presumably, is on your server).  If you want it to resolve to a different server, you need to use an absolute URL -- e.g., `http://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=btc_usd`.